# Mac OSX sqlite api for C++

Tags: macos, sqlite

I am porting a C# program on mac and the component I am doing has the feature to manipulate database. adding removing / updating records etc.
In the original program there is a s3db file that gets shipped and the program uses System.Data.SQLite.dll to interact with database.

Since I am working on macox and I am pretty new to it, all the back end is being written in C/C++ I am not sure what mac has to offer for sqllite,

So my question is: 
Is there a build in support api in mac for sqlite ? or Do I need to use a separate sqlite C/C++ lib or mac already gives something that I can use ?
Is it ok to ship s3db on mac osx or any existing built in way to create dbs in mac?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac OS X comes with sqlite 3:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/*sqlite*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel       16 Aug 25 10:22 /usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib@ -> libsqlite3.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  2216304 Sep 18 19:16 /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel       27 Aug 25 10:29 /usr/lib/sqlite3@ -> /System/Library/Tcl/sqlite3


$ ls -l /usr/include/*sqlite*
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  336911 Oct 23 10:24 /usr/include/sqlite3.h
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   24158 Oct 23 10:24 /usr/include/sqlite3ext.h
```

Comment: Thanks , and the db files ? have to be shipped with the package ? what is that norm in mac osx ??

Comment: Presumably the database is specific to your application, right?  How is the user going to get that data if you don't send it to them?

Comment: Basically on windows we ship empty db file which just has empty tables in it, when users use the app, the app internally pushes data to those tables, So I was wondering if I can also somehow create schema on the first run ?

Comment: sqlite is the same whatever system you run it on, you should be able to do exactly the same thing.