# Mac OS X Lion does not have /usr/include folder?

Tags: xcode, macos

I have been trying to use SQLite API in a C++ program but I can not find the SQLite include files. I was told in this post [Mac OSX sqlite api for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205366/mac-osx-sqlite-api-for-c) that sqlite is alerady present on Mac OS X and headers can be found /usr/include.

I have a recently purchased MacBook Pro with Mac OS X Lion, Xcode 4.3.2 and there is no include folder in the /usr folder.  /usr contains

```
  X11
  X11R6
  bin
  clang-ide
  lib
  libexec
  local
  sbin
  share
  standalone
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would reinstall Xcode and its command line tools as /usr/include should be there.

Comment: This isn't very relevant to the problem you ask about, but you can run Xcode 4.6 on Lion.

Comment: Run `xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to [download and install the Xcode command-line tools](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/1006-SW2). That link shows you how to do it from within Xcode.

Comment: thanks, I am downloading the command line tools, from within xode which is painfully slow for some reason. I will come back with my feedback ..